# Variable and if statement producing error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using notepad ++ for my JS code. 
In the first line I declared variable a and assigned value zero.
Then we try to get it to say if a is greater than or equal to 0 and less than 5 display the words within range.
Tested this on the online JS sandbox platform and it's giving a syntax error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>

var a = 0;

  if (a >= 0) {
    return "Within range";
  } 

    if (a > 5) {
    return "Within range";
  } 

</script>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: You `return` from a function. Try `alert()` or `console.log()`

Comment: Are we to assume you want to display the words on the webpage or a popup like alert()

Comment: `This is for a college assignment, so there will be no HTML or CSS syntax.`  I have no idea what you mean by this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `alert()` as @j08691 mentioned or use `.innerHTML` to display it on your webpage

```js
var r = document.getElementById("result");

var a  =6;

if(a >= 0){
  alert("In Range"); // you can alert the result here
  r.innerHTML = "In Range";
}else if(a > 5){
  alert("In Range");
  r.innerHTML = " In Range";
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This has been hugely helpful, however both statements need to say in range, tried to change that and it came back with an error. :S

Comment: @PatriciaBeateLulle I edited the above code to make it both say "In Range" with an alert